# .ipa working in devices if Build is used vs not working when Archive is used("Unable to install xyz App"). {UDID's are shown in both cases}

Tags: ios, xcode, build, archive

When i install .ipa of my app using Build in Xcode it works fine in my device whereas when i use Archive to create .ipa of my app and install it in my device it shows "Unable to install xyz App".

Comment: Have you created a AdHoc distribution profile, and are you using it (and not Dev profile) to create your archive?

Comment: How do you try to install ? Via itms url ?

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke Firstly i was using Dev Profile but after using AdHoc Profile also the app created using Archive is showing the same error.

Comment: @PtitXav by connecting iphone to mac or creating app from website betafamily.com/supersend